# FireFox addon-sdk page-worker regex

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

According to MDN's page [page-worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker), I should be able to use a Reg-ex as an argument to the include section of my function.

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var page = require("sdk/page-worker");
var re = new RegExp("/.*google.*/");

function doTheThing(){
    page.Page({
        include: re,
        contentURL: data.url("webPage.html"),
        contentScriptWhen: "ready",
        contentScript: 'document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";'
    })
}
```

What this code does is that when a tab loads in the browser, it should check the url and if it has google as part of it, my ContentScript should run. The problem is that I get the following error..

```
 Message: RequirementError: The option "include" must be one of the following types: string, array, undefined
```

Why can I not use a Reg-ex as my argument? The API clearly states that Reg-ex are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the docs don't match the initialization code for page-worker, and I think the bug is that it checks only for strings or arrays. I found that if you enclose the regex object in an array, this works:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var page = require("sdk/page-worker");
var re = new RegExp("/.*google.*/");

function doTheThing(){
    page.Page({
        include: [re], // only accepts regex objects in an array
        contentURL: data.url("webPage.html"),
        contentScriptWhen: "ready",
        contentScript: 'document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";'
    })
}
```

I've logged this bug to track the issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138545